# Under which conditions the collision front between two bodies stops?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Imagine body 1 and body 2. Each body is made up of $n$ and $m$ deformable elements, respectively, all with elastoplastic behaviour.

Body 1 and body 2 are aligned vertically and body 1 falls from an initial Z coordinate onto body 2.

Body 1 is stationary before falling.
Body 2 is stationary before body 1 collides with it and it is clamped down on a rigid surface at the base.

My general questions are the following :

1. What will make body 1 come to a stop after it collides with body 2?
2. Alternatively, what conditions need to be fulfilled in order that the collision front of body 1 into body 2 and possibly internally in body 2 comes to halt?
3. Is it necessary that all kinetic energy be converted in potential energy (ignoring other types of energy conversion) for the above to happen?

Note that it is a possible case that the elements of body 1 and their connections to each other can be potentially weak and can break during collision so that body 1 actually disintegrates during collision. The same applies to body 2 elements.

4. How can these questions be answered using the law of conservation of momentum and energy?

Comment: The energy does not convert into deformation. It converts into deformation and heat. As tempting as your proposition 3) is, it's unphysical. If you want a treatment using nothing but conservation of momentum and energy, then you don't need to model the details about the bodies to begin with. You are getting the "full theory" at that level from the inelastic collision formula of high school physics. If you were to apply the same procedure to segmented body models, then you get one arbitrary "inelastic energy loss" term per segment and one inelastic deformation displacement term per link.

Answer (score 0):

If one piece of moist clay is dropped onto another piece of moist clay which is sitting on a rigid surface,  all of the energy of the upper piece will be converted to heat as both pieces are deformed. In the collision, the momentum of the upper piece will be transferred to the earth.

Comment: thanks. Your example is clear but it misses to show what general principles one needs to invoke to show that the collapse is stopped or is not.

Comment: Unless body 1 penetrates the rigid surface, it must be stopped by a reaction force from that surfaces, which holds body 2 in place.

Comment: That is true regardless of body 2 exists or does not exist. Whereas the focus of the question is on how the presence of body 2 can influence the progress of the colliding motion of body 1